# Why objects are not recognized if declared after the function that uses them

Tags: javascript

Here is a simple example: I have two functions: `someFunction` and `someFunction2`.

`someFunction` recognizes `someFunction2` event thoug it is defined after `someFunction`. It is different with the object `someVar` thoug. If it is defined after the function that uses it, it is not recognized by the function hence `undefined`. But if the object is defined before the funcution that uses it the function itself recognizes the objec. Here is an example that showcase:

```
function someFunction() {
    console.log(someVar)
    someFunction2()
}

someFunction()

function someFunction2() {
    console.log("Some Function 2 has been called")
}

var someVar = 'Some Var Displayed Here'
```

In the case above `someFunction` recognizes `someFunction2` but doesn't recognize the object `someVar` WHY? what is the difference between the `someFunction2` and `someVar`?

Comment: Obviously because `someFunction()` is called **before** `someVar` definition. Just move `someFunction()` call somewhere after `someVar`.

Comment: @hindmost
I know that but this is not the case with `someFunct2`. What is the difference in calling `someFunction2` or evoking `someVar`?

Comment: Named function declarations and variable declarations are hoisted, but assignment statements are not.

Comment: @4castle
If you suggest this as an answer I would accept it!

Comment: Then is a function definition a function declaration as well?

Comment: Once a question is marked as a duplicate, it can't get new answers.

Comment: It is very sad. If I knew the about the term `hoisting` I wouldn't ask such a question at all.

Comment: A "function definition" isn't a phrase the JavaScript community uses, so I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: Anyway, function is acknowledged event if it is "defined" after its invocation, but with variables like string var for e.g. is not. That is very strange to me.